# action complete notification

Tags: javascript, jsf

I'm new in JSF. I'm working on some table with many rows. I want to delete some row:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{users.deleteSelectedUsers}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"  value="Delete Users">
```

After deleting I want to add a new row on top of the table with notification with some info. To which event I can add the function? If I'm putting <f:ajax> between <h:commandButton> the table is not rendered.

Comment: Haven't you said you're using RichFaces? You can use the `oncomplete` method to fire javascript actions. The method can be found in `<a4j:commandButton>` and `<a4j:commandLink>` tag components (just to mention some).

Answer (score 0):

You should add `<f:ajax render="@form">` so that the form with the table will be refreshed...